# Perl- How can I access a variable when I set I used <STDIN> for user to set it within a loop?

Tags: perl, loops, variables, stdin

I've written a script that requires the user to input a response which is saved as a variable.  The problem is that I used a loop to do this and I have a second question that requires user input but this is outside of the first loop. The output from the second question requires that both the first variable & the second variable meet the condition which prints a response. I get the error message (using warnings) that the variable is not explicitly declared.

How can I prompt Perl to "remember" the user input from *in* the loop after the loop is over?  Should I just continue the loop? If so, how?

Thanks for your help. I've attached the script. I assume it's unsophisticated and that it may be better to use a different type of loop but I'm just getting the hang of the for fxn so it would be helpful to stick to it.  Any other tips in cleaning up the code would be helpful.

```
#!C:\Perl
#lesson2XUE.pl
use warnings; use strict;

my $fas="MTESMIRDVELAEEALPKKTGGPQG";
my $swi="MSTESMIRDV ELAEEALPKK TGGPQG";
print "Your sequence has been determined. How would you like it displayed? FASTA/SwissProt:";

for ( my $i=0; $i<4; $i++ ) {
my $choice=<STDIN>;
chomp $choice;
if ($choice =~ /FASTA/i) { 
    print $fas,"\n";
    last;
} elsif ($choice =~ /SwissProt/i){
    print $swi,"\n";
    last;
} else {
        print qq[Please type "FASTA" or "SwissProt" only\n]; 
}       
}

sleep (1);
print "\n";

print qq[Would you like to see the other version? Y/N\n];
my $choice2=<STDIN>;
chomp $choice2;
    if (($choice2 =~ /Y/i) && **($choice =~ /FASTA/i)**){ 
        print $swi,"\n";
} elsif (($choice2=~/Y/i) && **($choice=~/SwissProt/i)**) {
        print $fas, "\n";
} elsif ($choice2 =~ /N/i) {
        print qq[Okay,have a good day];
}
```

The issue occurs where the script is bold.  Because I am no longer in the loop, $choice is not defined.

problem with  **if (($choice2 =~ /Y/i) && **($choice =~ /FASTA/i)**){**  and  **} elsif ($choice =~ /SwissProt/i)** (Realised that I cannot bold in 'script' view)

Thanks again!

Comment: You declare `$choice` inside the loop, so that's its lexical scope. If you want to access it outside the loop, declare it outside the loop.

Comment: Right, I read this on other questions. But how do I declare something that the user input? If I use <STDIN> again it would wait for more user input.  How do I re-declare user input?

Comment: Outside the loop: `my $choice;` Inside the loop: `$choice = <STDIN>;`

Comment: Thanks! Now I'm getting a different error though "use of uninitialized value $choice in pattern match (m//) at line 30, <STDIN> line 2." Your help is so appreciated!

Comment: Other comments. If you use `foreach` only to set the number of iterations, you can say `for (1..4)` (that `$i` is unused).  This will go through the loop four times, while inside the loop the [special variable $_](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#General-Variables) will have the current number at each iteration.

Comment: That would be `for (0..3)` if you wish the _same_ numbers as in your `foreach` (which you probably don't since `$i` isn't being used).

Comment: This is just advice to clean up the script, right?  I changed it to what you suggested. To verify I understand, this is a shorter way to have the loop repeated 4 times. Thank you

Comment: Okay, to reiterate:

Matt Jacob- When I tried to declare my $choice outside the loop I got a new error message that $choice is uninitialized (see above). All I did was added my$choice; outside of the loop.
I cannot initially declare outside of the loop because I need the user input portion to be repeated each time if the incorrect response was input.
Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Yes, right -- there is nothing wrong with what you have.  Just ... the C-style `for` loop is practically _never_ needed in Perl.

Comment: Declaring `$choice` outside the loop is exactly what you need to do. Since I have no way of seeing your screen and knowing what you did, you should [edit] your question to additionally include the new information.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before... Declare $choice outside the scope of your loop. in your example $choice is out of scope after leaving the for loop...

```
use warnings; use strict;

my $fas="MTESMIRDVELAEEALPKKTGGPQG";
my $swi="MSTESMIRDV ELAEEALPKK TGGPQG";
print "Your sequence has been determined. How would you like it displayed? FASTA/SwissProt:";
my $choice="";
for (my $i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
$choice=<STDIN>;
chomp $choice;
if ($choice =~ /FASTA/i) { 
    print $fas,"\n";
    last;
} elsif ($choice =~ /SwissProt/i){
    print $swi,"\n";
    last;
} else {
        print qq[Please type "FASTA" or "SwissProt" only\n]; 
}       
}

sleep (1);
print "\n";

print qq[Would you like to see the other version? Y/N\n];
my $choice2=<STDIN>;
chomp $choice2;
    if (($choice2 =~ /Y/i) && ($choice =~ /FASTA/i)){ 
        print $swi,"\n";
} elsif (($choice2=~/Y/i) && ($choice=~/SwissProt/i)) {
        print $fas, "\n";
} elsif ($choice2 =~ /N/i) {
        print qq[Okay,have a good day];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think these would be help.

```
while(defined($line=<STDIN>)){
    print "I saw $line";
}
```

I made a version:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $fas = "MTESMIRDVELAEEALPKKTGGPQG";
my $swi = "MSTESMIRDV ELAEEALPKK TGGPQG";

my $tmp = "";

main();

sub main () {
    print
"Your sequence has been determined. How would you like it displayed? FASTA/SwissProt:";
    while ( defined( my $line = <STDIN> ) ) {
        chomp $line;

        if ( $tmp eq "" ) {
            process($line);
            next;
        }
        else {
            process2($line);
            last;
        }
    }
}

sub process {
    my $choice = shift;
    $tmp = $choice;
    if ( $choice =~ /FASTA/i ) {
        print $fas, "\n";
    }
    elsif ( $choice =~ /SwissProt/i ) {
        print $swi, "\n";
    }
    else {
        $tmp = "";
        print qq[Please type "FASTA" or "SwissProt" only\n];
        return;
    }
    print "\n";
    print qq[Would you like to see the other version? Y/N\n];
}

sub process2 {
    my $choice2 = shift;
    if ( ( $choice2 =~ /Y/i ) && ( $tmp =~ /FASTA/i ) ) {
        print $swi, "\n";
    }
    elsif ( ( $choice2 =~ /Y/i ) && ( $tmp =~ /SwissProt/i ) ) {
        print $fas, "\n";
    }
    elsif ( $choice2 =~ /N/i ) {
        print qq[Okay,have a good day];
    }
    else {
        print qq[Good day];
    }
}
```